# Problem with fullscreen minecraft reftesh rate

Tags: minecraft, fullscreen

i have connected a new 75ghz monitor and my computer runnuing ubuntu 15.04.
I have amd apu and in AMD control center i have selected 75ghz and it working perfectly, but while i launching minecraft and entering fullscreen, it changes to 60ghz. Any help?
P.s. sorry for my english :p

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr) command to see if the one you selected is available on your system?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't help

Comment: Ive done some reading and according to the forums I have read by default minecraft runs the same display mode that your desktop is set to. They also noted that the program optifine can change it.